# Sum multiple objects in multiple arrays and then average sums

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a object with the name, race number` (1,2,3) and finishing position of  multiple drivers. I want to iterate through each array and display (console.log is fine) the race number, finishing position and then average finishing position for each driver.

Below is the data and desired output:

```
{
"drivers":[
    {
        "Name":"Smith",
            "races": [
            {
                "race 1":"12"
            },
            {
                "race 2":"6"
            },
            {
                "race 3":"10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name":"Jones",
            "races": [
            {
                "race 1":"11"
            },
            {
                "race 2":"6"
            },
            {
                "race 3":"5"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
    Smith:
    Race 1 finishing position: 12
    Race 2 finishing position: 6
    Race 3 finishing position: 10
    Average finishing position: 9.3

    Jones:
    Race 1 finishing position: 11
    Race 2 finishing position: 6
    Race 3 finishing position: 5
    Average finishing position: 7.3
```

Comment: FYI: Don't talk about JSON when you refer to plain, regular Javascript objects, like in this case. JSON is a serialization format. It is not what you are working with here. That being said, please show your efforts so far. You have outlined what you need to do, you must have started doing it. Show us where you are stuck. (Otherwise this is a "please write this code for me" type of question, which usually catch downvotes here on SO.)

Comment: @Tomalak  In what way is the above not JSON?.

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation. (JSON) is a syntax for storing and exchanging data.

Comment: @Keith In the way that JSON is a string and nothing but a string. It never is an object with arrays in it. It is a *serialization format* for structured data. [data] =(serialization)=> [JSON] =(parsing)=> [data]. And the question above is not about time middle part of this life-cycle. JS objects and JSON are not the same thing.

Comment: @Tomalak  Copy and paste the above string (JSON), into a JSON validator. http://jsonlint.com/#  Oh, it's a totally valid JSON.  FYI. JSON does arrays.

Comment: @Keith Stop being so smug, of course it passes as JSON. Try to understand what I am saying in my comment instead.

Comment: @Tomalak There is nothing complicated here, it's valid JSON,why are you trying to over complicate things.

Comment: I am not complicating things, you are making them too simple. JSON is not an object. Try to understand that statement. JSON has no keys, it contains no arrays and has no values. JSON is a **string** with a few colons and braces in it. It cannot be iterated. Before you can do anything with it you need to parse it, at which point it stops being JSON and starts being an object graph in whatever host language you decided to parse it with. Which could be something other than JavaScript. JSON and "objects" are different things, and the OPs question is not about JSON, but about objects.

Comment: @Tomalak I know what JSON is, and is not!!.. Your comment `It is not what you are working with here`,  I have issues with, because JSON was exactly what he was working with,. It certainly was not a plain object.  We can go back and forwards on this issues, but it's a bit pointless, as you will find some condescending retro-rick to swing back this way.

Comment: Look, I have no interest in fighting with you. You asked me about the difference between JSON and objects, and I explained it as detailed as possible. It wasn't supposed to be condescending, it was supposed to be extensive. It's a common misconception (and apparently one you also share) to think of JSON and objects as the same thing, just because it integrates so easily with Javascript that one might forget that there is parsing involved here at all. In other languages the difference is much more obvious.

Comment: @Keith Tomalak is 100% correct.  The OP does not have JSON, they have a (nested) _JavaScript literal_ which happens to look (if it were stringified) almost exactly like JSON.

Comment: @Alnitak  No, it's JSON, or it wouldn't pass a JSON validator.  In fact I'd say it looks more like JSON than a Javascript literal, as a javascript literal although can double quote it's keys, is normally not done.. eg.  `"Name":"Smith"` instead of `Name:"Smith"`.

Comment: @Keith yes, of course it passes, because when you paste this JS literal into a validator that validator _treats the input as a string_ and then passes it to a JSON parser.  And yes, not all valid JS literals would work, because of the double quoting.  If anything, that subverts your argument, because it reinforces that not all JSON object literals are trivially converted to JSON simply by wrapping the whole thing in quotes to stringify it.  JSON is strictly a _data interchange_ format, and data should only be called that when in its serialised form.

Comment: @Alnitak It was in it's serialised form, right at the top of the OP's question.  What other serialised format are you on about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just loop it and to get the race no use Object.keys()

```js
 var data = {
        "drivers":[
        {
            "Name":"Smith",
                "races": [
                {
                    "race 1":"12"
                },
                {
                    "race 2":"6"
                },
                {
                    "race 3":"10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name":"Jones",
                "races": [
                {
                    "race 1":"11"
                },
                {
                    "race 2":"6"
                },
                {
                    "race 3":"5"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };


    for(var x in data.drivers) {
        console.log(data.drivers[x].Name + ":");
        var total = 0;
        for(var i in data.drivers[x].races) {
            var key = Object.keys(data.drivers[x].races[i]);
            total += parseInt(data.drivers[x].races[i][key]);
            console.log(key+ " finishing: "+data.drivers[x].races[i][key]);
        }
        console.log('Average finishing position: ' + (total/3).toFixed(1));
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you Newbee Dev! In response to @Tomalak, who wanted me to show what I've done, well, I wasn't even close. This is a learning experience for me - probably way over my head at this point but what Newbee Dev has done/shown me helps tremendously! Interesting debate on whether this is JSON as well. I believe it is but again, I'm a novice. ;)

Comment: -1 for lots of newbee repetition in the object dereferencing and newbee use of `for .. in` on an array (it's supposed to be used for property iteration, not array indexing)

Comment: it would deserve another, if I could, for the hard coded assumption that there are three races in each list.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate `array`
Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the `Object`

```js
var obj = {
  "drivers": [{
    "Name": "Smith",
    "races": [{
      "race 1": "12"
    }, {
      "race 2": "6"
    }, {
      "race 3": "10"
    }]
  }, {
    "Name": "Jones",
    "races": [{
      "race 1": "11"
    }, {
      "race 2": "6"
    }, {
      "race 3": "5"
    }]
  }]
};
obj.drivers.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.Name + ':');
  var total = 0;
  el.races.forEach(function(race) {
    var key = Object.keys(race)[0];
    total += +race[key];
    console.log(key + ' finishing position :' + race[key]);
  });
  console.log('Average finishing position :' + total / el.races.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is generic to any number of users and their races in JSON object given

`jsonObj.drivers.forEach(function(obj) {
    var len = obj.races.length;
    console.log(obj.Name+":");
    var avrg = 0
    for(var j=0;j<obj.races.length;j++){
       var x = j+1;
       var key = "race "+x;
       var race = parseInt(obj.races[j][key]);
       avrg +=race;
       console.log("Race "+(j+1)+" finishing position: "+race);
  }
console.log("Average finishing position: "+(avrg/len).toPrecision(2));
});`